# Android NDK open() device permission denied

Tags: android, permissions, android-ndk, java-native-interface, v4l2

In a native call, I'm trying to `open("/dev/video4", O_RDWR)` but I get errno EACCES 13 "permission denied".

If I run the same code* in an executable, on the same Android host, as the same UID of the installed app I'm running above, it works fine. (* minor differences like `main()` instead of `Java_com_test_testOpen()`)

I've tried `chmod 666 /dev/video4` and still get EACCES, which is especially strange.

Why does the *same code*, on the *same host*, as the *same user*, give EACCESS when called via JNI, and success when called as standalone executable?

The test device is rooted and running Cyanogenmod 12.1 (API 22) and I'm targeting >= API 21 (5.0 Lollipop) on rooted devices. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's SELinux - dmesg has entries like: `avc: denied { read write } for pid=2495 comm="est.v4l2test" name="video4" dev="tmpfs" ino=15110 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:video_device:s0 tclass=chr_file`. I'll post an answer once I get it all sorted. For now, `echo 0 > /sys/fs/selinux/enforce` does the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm building Cyanogenmod 12.1 (API 22) with other minor hacks I was able to get permissions for `/dev/video*` in my app by using the following hacks:

1. For standard Linux permissions, `android.permission.CAMERA` no longer seems to allow access to `/dev/video*` even though they're owned by `system:camera`. Instead, I edited `device/samsung/klte-common/rootdir/etc/ueventd.qcom.rc` and changed the `/dev/video*` line to `0666`.
2. For SE Linux permissions, I added the line `allow untrusted_app video_device:chr_file rw_file_perms;` to `external/sepolicy/untrusted_app.te`.

After rebuilding and installing the image, my JNI lib is able to access `/dev/video*` and my client is happy!

Answer (score 1):

Since you get an error when running your code from an Android Java application, I would guess that you are missing a permission. It's the camera that you are trying to access, if I am not mistaken, so if you add:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml, your application should run fine.

Comment: Thank you but I have that! My understanding is that this permission adds your app UID to the camera GID but the chmod 666 overrides this anyway. Also, I discovered that this was removed in API 22+ for security reasons (can't currently find the commit or reference).

Answer (score 0):

The answers was not enough for me, so I left one more anwser.
open API has more parameter 'mode'.

> int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);

check out the link http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

you might need to use 'open' with S_IRWXU option.
like

> open("/dev/video4", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU )